# Batch Script - set the exe properties automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

I have an exe i want to set from inside the batch script its compatibility for windows XP sp3 
using batch script

So for example if i right click i get a dialog as

```
 'candle' properties
```

In this i choose

```
 'compatibility' option
```

There is a check box and text written is

```
 'Run this program in compatibiltiy mode for '
```

Then there is a list of available OS i want to replicate the same inside my batch file

Answer (score 2):

From this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line)

```
reg.exe Add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Test.exe" /d "WINXPSP3"
```

Available compatibility modes:

```
Value         Description
WIN95         Windows 95
WIN98         Windows 98
WIN4SP5       Windows NT 4.0 SP5
WIN2000       Windows 2000
WINXPSP2      Windows XP SP2
WINXPSP3      Windows XP SP3
VISTARTM      Vista
VISTASP1      Vista SP1
VISTASP2      Vista SP2
WIN7RTM       Windows 7 
WINSRV03SP1   Windows Server 2003 SP1
WINSRV08SP1   Windows Server 2008 SP1
```